# How can I decompile an ARM Cortex-M0 .hex file to C++?

Tags: arm, decompile

The source file is in intel 32 bit .hex format, it was built for a nuvoton NUC220LE3AE. I want to decompile it to C++, or at least assembly. I have some experience with assembly, but mostly with MIPS and that was years ago - so high level code is preferred.

Link to .hex file: http://www.3fvape.com/images/3fvape-blog-img/20150806-4384-xcubeII-upgrade/SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex

The device it resides in is a SMOK Xcube 2 (e-cig box mod.)

My goal is to add an option to control the LED color based on the atomizer temperature.

I searched but could not find an applicable how-to.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: You can't.

At least, don't expect a readable, and compilable, C source code. There's discussion why elsewhere on this site, so i won't get into details.

Also, note there's not an easy walk-through or how-to. You need to experiment, and you'll need some experience as well.

To get you started, you might:

- convert the .hex file into a raw binary file, for example using [Hex2bin](http://hex2bin.sourceforge.net/)
- use that binary file with the [retargetable Decompiler](https://retdec.com/decompilation/) selecting "raw machine code" and probably "ARM+Thumb" as architecture
- If the results of of the retargetable decompiler are unsatisfactory (it didnt work well for me, last time i tried), you might want to try the [Online Disassembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) to get assembly code
- Of course, the ultimate tool is [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com), but the freeware version can't handle ARM, and the price is probably a bit steep for a hobby project.

Comment: The online disassebmler only supports up to armv5, but the coretex m0 this is based on uses armv6.

I think my company has a license for IDA, but I've gotta ask around on the specifics.

Comment: You could just use `<yourarch>-objdump -b binary -xD file.bin` on the raw binary.

Answer (score 3):

radare2 supports these ihex files directly

note the command in radare2 in my original answer uses switch -b32 
SYS_V commented that it should be -b16 and posted an answer with ample details how to proceed from the end of my answer to a tangible result here is the link to that thread [how to find usefull info from a bin file](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15006/approach-to-extract-useful-information-from-binary-file)

```
:\>ls -l
total 172
-rw-rw-rw-  1 Admin 0 172401 2016-01-01 00:44 SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex

:\>rahash2 -a md5 SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex
SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex:0x00000000-0x0002a170 md5: 351660a42b846d19e35f54f75530e2d9

:\>radare2 -A -a arm -b 32 ihex://SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex
Function too big at 0xa50e54
Function too big at 0xfe25a2ac
Function too big at 0x1648234
Function too big at 0x13ed738
[0x00000000]> s 0xc1
[0x000000c1]> pd 10
|          0x000000c1    4885460c       mcrreq p5, 4, r8, r6, c8
|          0x000000c5    f070fc00       ldrshteq r7, [ip], 0
|          0x000000c9    480047e9       stmdb r7, {r3, r6} ^
|          0x000000cd    1b0000e8       stmda r0, {r0, r1, r3, r4}
|          0x000000d1    0e002004       strteq r0, [r0], -0xe
|          0x000000d5    48804704       strbeq r8, [r7], -0x48
|          0x000000d9    480047fe       cdp2 p0, 4, c0, c7, c8, 2
|          0x000000dd    e7fee7fe       cdp2 p14, 0xe, c15, c7, c7, 7
|          0x000000e1    e7fee7fe       cdp2 p14, 0xe, c15, c7, c7, 7
|          0x000000e5    e7fee75d       stclpl p14, c15, [r7, 0x39c]!
[0x000000c1]>
```

if you were wondering how did radare2 get the 4885460c at address 0xxxxc1 
then read further

intel seems to have published the specs of ihex file format i got hold of one pdf from microsym named intelhex.pdf  dont know if any latest version are available this is my first brush with ihex or arm for that matter

```
Hexadecimal Object File Format Specification Revision A January 6, 1988
```

based on the description in the file

it seems each line in the ihex file starts with a <kbd>colon :</kbd>
followed by ONE BYTE     = record length
followed by TWO BYTES    = offset to load
followed by ONE BYTE     = Record Type
Last BYTE in the line    = Checksum

each of the above are hexpairs ie BYTE E8 will be 0x45 0x38 in the file

```
3A 31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 45 38 30 45 30 30 :10000000E80E00
```

the file consists of 3833 lines out of which 3830 lines have a record length of 0x10

```
wc SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex
  3833   3833 172401 SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex

grep -ivn :10 SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex
1::020000040000FA
3832::04000005000000C136
3833::00000001FF
```

dissecting the first line

```
line1 data size   = 0x02 
load offset       = 0x0000
record type is    = 0x04  (extended linear address 32 bit format)
```

and it stays as is until another record 04 is encountered lets check if the file contains another record 04

```
:\>grep -in :......04 SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex
1::020000040000FA
```

only one line
the last line 3833 denotes end of file `record type 0x01`
the last but one line denotes start linear address `record type 0x05`  and EIP = 0xc1   checksum matches `(100 - (0xc1 + 0x05 + 0x04 ) ) == 0x36`

so that leaves 3830 lines as code data xx

based on the above details we can carve the bytes

delete the `first , last . last but one` lines from the input file
`sed substitute` the first nine characters and last two character and `rip off the line endings \r\n` .

```
sed s/:........//g < in | sed s/..$//g | tr -d  "\r\n" > out
```

lets check out if sed magic worked  we should have 32 characters per line if it worked concatenated into one big string

```
:\>wc out
     0      1 122560 out

:\>set /a 32*3830
122560
```

lets convert the hex pairs to binary

```
rax2 -s < out > bin
```

this doesn't work as it should deliver us half the input size but it is higher than that also the inversion `rax2 -S < bin > is_original`  doesn't get us the original input back

to the developers of radare if you read this can you check if rax2 -s works properly in windows if input is file  it seems it suffers from unix / windows line ending quirks (windows seems to convert the binary 0x0A to 0x0d 0x0a when using the redirection operator

```
:\>rax2 -s < out > bin

:\>wc bin
  616  4126 61896 bin

:\>set /a 61896 * 2
123792
```

lets cook a python unhexlify

```
:\>cat makebin.py
import binascii
fp = open("out","rb")
fo = open("bin","wb")
buff = fp.read()
fo.write(binascii.unhexlify(buff))
fp.close()
fo.close()
:\>python makebin.py

:\>wc *
   616   4126  61280 bin
  3830   3830 172350 in
     6     14    139 makebin.py
     0      1 122560 out
   616   4126  61896 rax2bin
  5068  12097 418225 total

:\>set /a 61280*2
122560
:\>
```

python seems to deliver us the correct bytes

lets ask radare2 if the size 122560 is right

```
[0x000000c1]> if
file     ihex://SMOK_X_CUBE_II_firmware_v1.07.hex
fd       2357404
size     0xef60
blksz    0x0
mode     r--
block    0x100
format   any

[0x000000c1]> !rax2 0xef60*2
122560
[0x000000c1]>
```

it seems to agree lets xxd and look if we fished the right bytes at right offset

```
:\>xxd -g 4 -l 32 -s 0xc1 bin
00000c1: 4885460c f070fc00 480047e9 1b0000e8  H.F..p..H.G.....
00000d1: 0e002004 48804704 480047fe e7fee7fe  .. .H.G.H.G.....
```

it looks right now we can try and start understanding the mnemonics 
(google doesn't seem to know much about mccreq i don't know arm so good-luck from here on

Comment: The target processor, ARM Cortex-M0,  uses a 16-bit Thumb instruction set even though its architecture is 32-bit

Comment: @SYS_V  thanks for the info i see you posted an answer to the other thread that refers to this question with lots of details  ill add a foot note to the answer referring to that thread and this comment

Comment: You are welcome. The explanation in this post of how to use r2 to disassemble `.hex` files was very useful