# Reverse Intel hex to programming code

Tags: assembly, disassemblers, hex, intel

I have a file in the Intel hex format, which was taken of from a pic16F1705 chip. I need to find a way to disassemble it into some form of human friendly programming language in order to make some modifications to it. I tried running it through a x86 and x64 dissembler, but in both cases I got an output, which looked like assembler code, but there were around 4000 bad lines in both cases.
My question is how should I disassemble this file, so I can read it in some human friendly programming language and modify it?

```
0:  02 00                   add    al,BYTE PTR [eax]
2:  00 04 00                add    BYTE PTR [eax+eax*1],al
5:  00 fa                   add    dl,bh
7:  10 00                   adc    BYTE PTR [eax],al
9:  00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
b:  80 31 0f                xor    BYTE PTR [ecx],0xf
e:  28 ff                   sub    bh,bh
10: 3f                      aas
11: ff                      (bad)
12: 3f                      aas
13: 7e 14                   jle    0x29
15: 80 31 20                xor    BYTE PTR [ecx],0x20
18: 00 7f 08                add    BYTE PTR [edi+0x8],bh
1b: a2 10 00 10 00          mov    ds:0x100010,al
20: f0 00 04 2e             lock add BYTE PTR [esi+ebp*1],al
24: 70 08                   jo     0x2e
```

These are some example lines of the output I get after running the hex through a x86/x64 dissembler.

Comment: you'll need to use a pic disassembler -- it's not x86 or x64. I know ida supports pic 16xx cpus and there's this disassembler (but I haven't tried it) https://github.com/fredimachado/PICHexDisassembler

Comment: I tried it using ida and got some results, so I will continue working from here. Thank you really much for your help!

Comment: iirc radare2 understands ihex format files i think i had a post but cant find it atm

Comment: Should work with radare2. Install radare2 [from git](https://github.com/radare/radare2) and execute `r2 ihex://filename`

Comment: @blabb, [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11692/18698), I assume

Comment: @Megabeets yes you found it right